# Can anybody help me with this python TypeError

Tags: python

As a new learner's question,this question may be very simple, but I have tried for many hours and cannot find the answer, sorry.

this is the a problem form edx's python course.

I will paste all of the code, But I have finished most of it and get correct。 The Part 4 is which I am going on.
first, the file's content is:

```
    # subject trigger named t1

    t1 SUBJECT world

    # title trigger named t2
    t2 TITLE Intel

    # phrase trigger named t3
    t3 PHRASE New York City

    # composite trigger named t4
    t4 AND t2 t3

    # the trigger set contains t1 and t4
    ADD t1 t4
```

,

```
import feedparser
import string
import time
from project_util import translate_html
from Tkinter import *


#======================
# Code for retrieving and parsing RSS feeds
#======================

def process(url):
    """
    Fetches news items from the rss url and parses them.
    Returns a list of NewsStory-s.
    """
    feed = feedparser.parse(url)
    entries = feed.entries
    ret = []
    for entry in entries:
        guid = entry.guid
        title = translate_html(entry.title)
        link = entry.link
        summary = translate_html(entry.summary)
        try:
            subject = translate_html(entry.tags[0]['term'])
        except AttributeError:
            subject = ""
        newsStory = NewsStory(guid, title, subject, summary, link)
        ret.append(newsStory)
    return ret

#======================
# Part 1
# Data structure design
#======================

class NewsStory(object):
    def __init__(self, guid, title, subject, summary, link):
        self.guid = guid
        self.title = title
        self.subject = subject
        self.summary = summary
        self.link = link        
    def getGuid(self):
        return self.guid        
    def getTitle(self):
        return self.title        
    def getSubject(self):
        return self.subject        
    def getSummary(self):
        return self.summary        
    def getLink(self):
        return self.link    

#======================
# Part 2
# Triggers
#======================

class Trigger(object):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        """
        Returns True if an alert should be generated
        for the given news item, or False otherwise.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError

# Whole Word Triggers

class WordTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word
    def changeText(self, text):
        for i in string.punctuation:
            text = text.replace(i, ' ')
        return text
    def isWordIn(self, text):
        return self.word.upper in self.changeText(self, text.upper()).split()

class TitleTrigger(WordTrigger):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.isWordIn(self, story.getTitle())

class SubjectTrigger(WordTrigger):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.isWordIn(self, story.getSubject())

class SummaryTrigger(WordTrigger):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.isWordIn(self, story.getSummary())


# Composite Triggers

class NotTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, trigger):
        self.trigger = trigger
    def evaluate(self,story):
        return not self.trigger.evaluate(story)
class AndTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, trigger1, trigger2):
        self.trigger1 = trigger1
        self.trigger2 = trigger2
    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.trigger1.evaluate(story) and self.trigger2.evaluate(story)   
class OrTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, trigger1, trigger2):
        self.trigger1 = trigger1
        self.trigger2 = trigger2
    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.trigger1.evaluate(story) or self.trigger2.evaluate(story)

# Phrase Trigger

class PhraseTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, phrase):
        self.phrase = phrase
    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.phrase in story.getSubject() or self.phrase in story.\
        getSummary() or self.phrase in story.getTitle()
#======================
# Part 3
# Filtering
#======================

def filterStories(stories, triggerlist):
    """
    Takes in a list of NewsStory instances.

    Returns: a list of only the stories for which a trigger in triggerlist fires.
    """
    temp = stories[:]
    for i in stories:
        for j in triggerlist:
            if (not j.evaluate(i)) and j == triggerlist[-1]:
                temp.remove(i)
            elif j.evaluate(i):
                break
    stories = temp[:]
    return stories
```

This is what I have done and get correct. because the next function needs TitleTrigger,SubjectTrigger,SummaryTrigger,NotTrigger,AndTrigger,PhraseTrigger,OrTrigger, and all the triggers need the NewsStory, so I keep them.

```
#======================
# Part 4
# User-Specified Triggers
#======================

def makeTrigger(triggerMap, triggerType, params, name):
    """
    Takes in a map of names to trigger instance, the type of trigger to make,
    and the list of parameters to the constructor, and adds a new trigger
    to the trigger map dictionary.
    triggerMap: dictionary with names as keys (strings) and triggers as values
    triggerType: string indicating the type of trigger to make (ex: "TITLE")
    params: list of strings with the inputs to the trigger constructor (ex: ["world"])
    name: a string representing the name of the new trigger (ex: "t1")
    Modifies triggerMap, adding a new key-value pair for this trigger.
    Returns a new instance of a trigger (ex: TitleTrigger, AndTrigger).
    """
    if triggerType == 'TITLE':
        triggerMap[name] = TitleTrigger
    if triggerType == 'SUBJECT':
        triggerMap[name] = SubjectTrigger
    if triggerType == 'PHRASE':
        triggerMap[name] = PhraseTrigger
    if triggerType == 'SUMMARY':
        triggerMap[name] = SummaryTrigger
    if triggerType == 'AND':
        triggerMap[name] = AndTrigger
    if triggerType == 'OR':
        triggerMap[name] = OrTrigger
    if triggerType == 'NOT':
        triggerMap[name] = NotTrigger

    if triggerType == 'AND' or triggerType == 'OR':
        tempt = triggerMap[name](triggerMap[params[0]],triggerMap[params[1]])
    elif triggerType == 'NOT':
        tempt = NotTrigger(triggerMap[params[0]])
    else:
        params = ' '.join(params)
        tempt = triggerMap[name](params)
    return tempt

def readTriggerConfig(filename):

    triggerfile = open(filename, "r")
    all = [ line.rstrip() for line in triggerfile.readlines() ]
    lines = []
    for line in all:
        if len(line) == 0 or line[0] == '#':
            continue
        lines.append(line)

    triggers = []
    triggerMap = {}

    for line in lines:

        linesplit = line.split(" ")

        # Making a new trigger
        if linesplit[0] != "ADD":
            trigger = makeTrigger(triggerMap, linesplit[1],
                                  linesplit[2:], linesplit[0])

        # Add the triggers to the list
        else:
            for name in linesplit[1:]:
                triggers.append(triggerMap[name])

    return triggers
```

This is the part I am working on, readTriggerConfig is given by teacher.

```
import thread

SLEEPTIME = 60 #seconds -- how often we poll


def main_thread(master):
    # A sample trigger list - you'll replace
    # this with something more configurable in Problem 11
    try:

        # TODO: Problem 11
        # After implementing makeTrigger, uncomment the line below:
        triggerlist = readTriggerConfig("triggers.txt")

        # **** from here down is about drawing ****
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

        t = "Google & Yahoo Top News"
        title = StringVar()
        title.set(t)
        ttl = Label(master, textvariable=title, font=("Helvetica", 18))
        ttl.pack(side=TOP)
        cont = Text(master, font=("Helvetica",14), yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        cont.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        cont.tag_config("title", justify='center')
        button = Button(frame, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
        button.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        # Gather stories
        guidShown = []
        def get_cont(newstory):
            if newstory.getGuid() not in guidShown:
                cont.insert(END, newstory.getTitle()+"\n", "title")
                cont.insert(END, "\n---------------------------------------------------------------\n", "title")
                cont.insert(END, newstory.getSummary())
                cont.insert(END, "\n*********************************************************************\n", "title")
                guidShown.append(newstory.getGuid())

        while True:

            print "Polling . . .",
            # Get stories from Google's Top Stories RSS news feed
            stories = process("http://news.google.com/?output=rss")

            # Get stories from Yahoo's Top Stories RSS news feed
            stories.extend(process("http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories"))

            # Process the stories
            stories = filterStories(stories, triggerlist)

            map(get_cont, stories)
            scrollbar.config(command=cont.yview)


            print "Sleeping..."
            time.sleep(SLEEPTIME)

    except Exception as e:
        print e


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Some RSS parser")
    thread.start_new_thread(main_thread, (root,))
    root.mainloop()
```

the last part is given by teacher.thanks

I add a method named getWord in the SubjectTrigger,TitleTrigger,PhraseTrigger,and AndTrigger to get the word, phrase to see whether the tempt is right or not, and I do this before return:

```
print tempt
print tempt.getWord()
return tempt
```

And it gives me:

```
<__main__.SubjectTrigger object at 0x000000000849B898>
world
<__main__.TitleTrigger object at 0x000000000849B8D0>
Intel
<__main__.PhraseTrigger object at 0x000000000849B898>
New York City
<__main__.AndTrigger object at 0x000000000849B8D0>
(<class '__main__.TitleTrigger'>, <class '__main__.PhraseTrigger'>)
Polling . . .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python\ProblemSet7\ps7.py", line 292, in main_thread
    stories = filterStories(stories, triggerlist)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python\ProblemSet7\ps7.py", line 161, in filterStories
    if (not j.evaluate(i)) and j == triggerlist[-1]:
TypeError: unbound method evaluate() must be called with SubjectTrigger instance as first argument (got NewsStory instance instead)
```

It seems like I have gotten the right tempt, but with some error in the line 161

Comment: could you please try to strip down your code to the least possible number of lines that still reproduces the problem? you are much more likely to get help this way...

Comment: Can you print out `params` after the line `params = ' '.join(params)` in the `makeTrigger` function. I have a feeling that that line is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the problem is this line of code:

```
WordTrigger.changeText(self, text.upper()).split()
```

You've defined `changeText` as an instance method, but you are calling it on the class itself. Try changing it to this:

```
self.changeText(text.upper()).split()
```

You'll also need to make similar transformations to the other subclasses of `WordTrigger`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is apparently an instance creation with an unexpected number of arguments, but the second problem is that you're discarding the traceback that would tell you precisely where. In your code:

```
def main_thread(master):
    # A sample trigger list - you'll replace
    # this with something more configurable in Problem 11
    try:
        pass  # Lots of code here
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

You catch any exception, and print only the exception. Normal behaviour would print a full traceback of where it occurred. Either remove this try-except clause entirely, or use the `traceback` module to restore the more informative message:

```
except:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
```

On further reading, it appears your core problems are in `makeTrigger`, specifically how it uses different types in `triggerMap`. It attempts to first assign a class into the map, then use that class to create an instance, but the logic is flawed:

```
if triggerType == 'AND' or triggerType == 'OR':
    tempt = triggerMap[name](triggerMap[params[0]],triggerMap[params[1]])
if triggerType == 'NOT':
    tempt = NotTrigger(triggerMap[params[0]])
else:
    params = ' '.join(params)
    tempt = triggerMap[name](params)
```

Firstly, as you have found, the first `if` is distinct from the later ones; this block is not three branches but two branching paths in sequence, easily fixed by using `elif`. Secondly, `triggerMap[name]` never gets set to the created instances. This breaks the assumption made in the logic triggers, where `triggerMap[params[n]]` are expected to be trigger instances, not classes. Trying to evaluate a triggerMap entry led to the unbound method call. One way to fix this is simply `triggerMap[name] = tempt`.

We could also reduce the special cases quite a bit; I would consider replacing the triggerType ifs with a dictionary, and perhaps using subclasses to choose between the parameter types (triggers, words or phrases).

Comment: I have fixed the problem of  the number of arguments which is precipitated by syntax error. And the main_thread is given by teacher,so I ignore this details about try...except, thanks

Comment: And what of the type discrepancy? The makeTrigger docstring indicates `triggerMap` should contain only instances, but you're putting classes in it. This is the cause of your `evaluate` type error.